# I can't create a Data Source in Pentaho CE

Tags: datasource, pentaho, pentaho-cde

I just install Pentaho Community Edition in my computer, but I am tryng to create a Data Source and I am unable to do that.

I follow all the process, I select the name of the Data Source, I select the conection and finally I press "finish" and the next message appear:

Creating/Updating Data Sorce.

but the software does not advance, It stay in the same message and the Datasource never is created.

in the begining I thought it was the firewall or the antivirus, but I disable that, and the incident still happends

Comment: What version of Pentaho are you using ?

Comment: Pentaho BI Platform 5.2.0.0

Comment: biserver-ce-5.2.0.0-209

Comment: What do the logs say ? What kind of datasource are you creating ?